# What to enter when asked `Provide Service AQccount` in TFS Server Configuration Wizard?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

When installing TFS Server 2010 on my server, I'm asked to provide the service account as below screenshot. I've tried `sa` and `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` account with admin password provided when installing SQL Server but all failed.

If you have any workaround for me, please share!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a valid user (non-system) account, such as yours, per the instruction on the page. You cannot use the system accounts, such as NETWORK SERVICE, here.

For more information:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253149.aspx#TFSMOSSAccts

Comment: Ah, hello Duat! So nice to see you here!

I've used `Administrator` tool and it works. Thank you!

Some suggestion: It would be nice to have a box to choose users.

Comment: Good to see you too Nam ;) The wizard exists before TFS is configured so you would have to get the list from the machine (unlike the dropdown list of users on a workitem). It's probably possible but it wouldn't have the same codepath like other places in TFS.